# how to create partitions when just computer is the only drive?

Tags: partitioning

I recently performed a clean installation of ubuntu 14.04 and have only computer in my devices tab in files.it has 1 tb and i want to divide it.I tried gparted but since ubuntu is in the same drive, its in use so i can't divide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create partition for any drive won which operating system is running. The only way to create partition on the system drive is by running ubuntu through a live cd. You may use lili to create a pendrive and using that you can run ubuntu from pen drive, and create partition of the system drive using gparted.

Answer (score 0):

Download Gparted and burn it on a CD. (http://gparted.org/livecd.php ).  This is a boot able CD.  Shutdown and boot with the Gparted CD.  At this moment there is no operation system running so you can make your partitions.